# How to store only product type/range on Opportunity when specific product choice unknown?

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, quote, product, quotelineitem

Because it's not possible to change a product once added to an opportunity, what's the standard way to store product family, qty, specifications, etc. while customer decides on the specific product?

Example: Kitchen contractor knows customer needs one white, 45 cm wide dishwasher but not the specific product or brand and will generate quotes with various products that meet product specifications.

How/where are the product specifications and qty stored/retrieved if specific product must be selected and is not changeable after entry?

Comment: note that OpportunityProducts can be deleted after entry and re-added once the finalized product is known

Answer (score 0):

Per comments: the standard method would seem to be using a generic Product and replacing it (deleting and re-adding) with a more specific one once the final product is determined.